# jquery easing problem

Tags: jquery, slideup, jquery-easing

I have what I thought was a simple piece of jquery, but it's turning out to be a pain.

The slideUp part of this works fine, but it doesn't then slide down... It does work though if I take out the easing part of the slideUp.

Any ideas?

```
   $('.clickableDiv').click(function() {
    $("<div style='background-image:url(../images/properties/images/bk-01.jpg); width:965px; height:398px;'><img src='../images/properties/text/bk.gif' width='965' height='398' /></div>").prependTo("div.myDiv2");

    $("div.myDiv1").slideUp(800, 'easeInOutSine', function() {
        $("div.myDiv2").slideDown(800, 'easeInOutSine');
    });    
});
```

myDiv2 is hidden initially.

Changing the line to this works which is why I am finding it a little odd...

```
$("div.myDiv1").slideUp(800, function() {
```

I'm using Safari and firefox on a mac to test it...

Comment: need to know which browser plz

Comment: @sje397, OP wanted for different divs. @Tom, to slideDown something, you should have it hidden or slidedUp or something.

Comment: @sje397 : totally wrong here. You're using the `click` event on the same `div`. quite not what the OP needs.

Comment: @Couchenos: I deleted the comment before you posted - but, 'totally wrong' is going a bit far :) As it turns out, whether it was the same div or not had nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the version of jQuery you're using.

From the manual :

> .slideUp( [
>   duration ], [ easing ], [ callback ] )
>   version added: 1.4.3

It means that if your version is < 1.4.3, it will only understand this :

> .slideUp( [ duration ], [ callback ] )

Example working with 1.4.4 :

http://www.jsfiddle.net/gMNL8/1/

Example not working with 1.2.6

http://www.jsfiddle.net/gMNL8/2/

**Source** : http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

*notes* : on my examples => `.myDiv2` is hidden to begin with.