# How can I make a div slide in with a easeoutbounce 4 seconds after page is finished loading?

Tags: jquery, html, pageload, sliding

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#online_bestellen").hide();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#online_bestellen").show()
    }, 4000);
    $('#online_bestellen').animate({
        bottom: '-=100px'
    }, 1500, 'easeOutBounce');
});
```

The div called `online_bestellen` hides and 4 seconds it appears again but it doesn't slide in..

Who has a better option?

Comment: Apparantly I solved it myself!                                              $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#online_bestellen").hide();
   setTimeout(function(){$("#online_bestellen").show()},4000);
   $('#online_bestellen').delay(4000).animate({bottom: '-=100px'}, 1500, 'easeOutBounce');
 });

Comment: I noticed that you have set bottom: '-=100px', maybe it has to be bottom: '-100px' so without the =?

Comment: No, it works fine now, just as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Its messy, but see if it works

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#online_bestellen").hide("fast", function(){
        $("#online_bestellen").show("fast", function(){
            $('#online_bestellen').animate({
                bottom: '-100px'
            }, 1500, 'easeOutBounce');
        })
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery [slideup api](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/).

Refer [jQuery Easing with slideUp Easing Function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19728818/3641101)